# how to config pip on osx when installed by brew?

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I install python using `brew` on mac and add a config file in `~/.pip/pip.conf`

```
[global]
index-url=http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple

[install]
trusted-host=http://mirrors.aliyun.com
```

But it doesn't work. When hit the command `pip install PIL`, it complains:

```
Collecting PIL
  The repository located at mirrors.aliyun.com is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com'.
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Please advice.

Comment: Pip works out of the box when installed with brew. Do you specifically need to use that repository?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, i want to use that repo. so as you mean, add a `pip.conf` should work?

Comment: Well, as the error says, the config works and the repository is known but not trusted. Either try via `https` or use the `--trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com` option.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is mark the repository as trusted for this run of pip:

```
pip install PIL --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com
```